# How can I use current_user and cookies in a class thats written in a controller's concern module?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

```
module DummyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    class DummyClass
      #I would like to use current_user and cookies here without initialising the class with any arguments!
    end
  end
end
```

I know it is possible by initialising this class with arguments outside of the class `DummyClass.new(current_user, cookies)` but is there any other prettier way to do it?

Comment: You could use `Thread.current` but that has some carried risk that you probably don't want to introduce. `ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes` came out in Rails 5 which solves this problem with a tidy abstraction, but you're using Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic way to do that.

`session` and `current_user` are methods that are only available in the context of a controller. When you want to use them in a model then you have to pass them to the model.

Or you have to assign them to something that is available in the context of the model. `Thread.current` or [`CurrentAttributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html) might be an option – as Josh already pointed out. But keep in mind these both ways have downsides too.

The clearest and safest way is to just pass them to the model in its `initialize` method.